# How to Split List in Flutter

Tags: dart

I have a list1: `var list1 = ["a:1", "b:2", "c:3"];`

how can I create `list2` based on list1 like this: `["a", "b", "c"]`

I thought I would have to use `split` and `forEach` but I don't know how to combine it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this works for you, if and only if you always have the same String length

```
  List<String> list1 = ["a:1", "b:2", "c:3"];
  List<String> list2 = list1.map((f) => f.substring(0,1)).toList();
```

Or if you wanted to have ":" as the basis regardless of the String length for each element then you can try the code below

```
  List<String> list1 = ["a:1", "b:2", "c:3"];
  List<String> list2 = list1.map((f) => f.split(":")[0]).toList();
```

Comment: Why not make your second solution like: `final list2 = [...list1.map((e) => e.split(':')[0])];`?

Comment: Using `Iterable.forEach` to add to a `List` is an inappropriate use of `forEach`.  Either use `map` or collection-for: `[for (var pair in list1) pair.split(':')[0]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all items of the list with forEach.
With every item (which is a string), split it using ':' as separator (or, if its always just one character, simply get the first charaxter of the item.
Add the first element of the result of split (or aimply first charaxter of item) to list2.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list1 = ["a:1", "b:2", "c:3"];
List list2;

list1.asMap().forEach((key, value) {
  list2.add(value.replaceAll(':${key + 1}', ''));
});
```

Here is my code